create xarchive with dotnet publish on windows
When publishing my Maui App for iOS on my windows machine through Visual Studio 2022 i receive a xarchive.
But when building with the dotnet publish cli i get an ipa file.
How can i configure dotnet publish so that it get me the xarchive just like using the VS22 user interface?
This is my current dotnet publish call:
dotnet publish $projectName -f net8.0-ios -c Release -o $iosOutput -p:ArchiveOnBuild=true -p:ServerAddress=$iosIpAddress -p:ServerUser=$iosUsername -p:TcpPort=58181 -p:_DotNetRootRemoteDirectory=/Users/$iosUsername/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/SDKs/dotnet/


You can refer to command line and xcarchive,try to set ArchiveOnBuild to false or Right-click the project ,then select Archive.
